# Excel 2010 VBA "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument" error in regex function

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm working with the following RegEx function in Excel 2010 and am getting the "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument" error on the last line of the function.  I substituted the ActiveCell.Value for the constant (commented out).  The constant did work properly, although the cell value does not.
What is causing this error to occur?
I appreciate any help in this.  Thanks.

```
Sub SUB1()
Dim c As Variant
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells
'MsgBox (c)
    If RE6(c.Value) Then
         c.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
         Else
         c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next
End Sub


Sub Test()
'Const strTest As String = "qwerty123456uiops"
Dim strTest As String
strTest = ActiveCell.Value
MsgBox RE6(strTest)
End Sub


Function RE6(strData As String) As String
Dim RE As Object
Dim REMatches As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
End With

Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
MsgBox ("REMatches.Count" & REMatches.Count)
'If Not REMatches Is Nothing Then
    If REMatches.Count <= 0 Then
    RE6 = ""
    Else
    RE6 = REMatches(0)
    End If
'Else

'End If


End Function
```

Comment: When you run this with `ActiveCell.Value`, does the active cell contain the text `qwerty123456uiops`?

Comment: If you intend to remove caracters from alphanumeric values, this can be done using an Excel Formula (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/extracting-numbers-from-alphanumeric-strings-HA001154901.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - I changed the pattern to [A-Z], and that came back with a result.  My initial pattern was different, and that resulted in the error.  I wouldn't have thought that a change in pattern could result in an error.  Maybe the data type?

Comment: The error is due to accessing index 0 of REMatches when REMatches is empty.   You should verify is REMatches is not empty before accessing the index, to prevent eventual errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to be aimed at testing whether a consecutive 6 digit number occurs in each cell in Sheet1 A1:D10, ie you are looking for a `Boolean` True/False so

1. Use a simpler pattern `Re.Pattern = "[0-9]{6}"`
2. Use the `Regexp` Test method - you don't need a collection of matches, just to know if one (as `Re.Global = False`) exists
3. Return a `Boolean` result from your function

   ```
   Function RE6(strData As String) As Boolean
   Dim RE As Object
   Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   With RE
       .MultiLine = False
       .Global = False
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Pattern = "[0-9]{6}"
       RE6 = .Test(strData)
   End With
   End Function
   ```

Comment: Would the 'RE.Execute' way be only if I did want that collection of matches?  ..and '.Test' only if I want one?

Comment: @buck1112 'Test' indicates if the regexp pattern is matched in the string of interest. If you want to either work with the first/collection of matches, or replace the first/colllection of matches insitu then you need 'Execute' or 'Replace' respectively. In your case you have set 'RE.Global = False' so your code will only retrun the first match - not a collection. You will need 'Re.Global=True' to work with a collection of matches

Answer (score 4):

Most likely there is no match: if you test the `.Count` property of REMatches is it zero?

Your function should test for that and return a suitable value (empty string maybe) instead.

**EDIT:** if you only want to check for the presence or absence of a pattern, then using `.Test()` is easier than using `.Execute()`.  I changed your function to return a Boolean, which is more natural in this type of case.

```
Sub CheckCellValues()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells
        If RE6(c.Value) Then
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
        Else
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function RE6(strData As String) As Boolean
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim REMatches As Object
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
    End With
    RE6 = RE.Test(strData) 'much simpler...
    'or...
    'REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
    'RE6 = (REMatches.Count > 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - I did do the test, and yes, it came back as zero.

Comment: No, I believe it's a Collection

Comment: Is the index zero-based?  In effect, if the count came back as zero, would the index be -1 or just non-existant?

Comment: It's zero-based, but if the collection is empty then there's no "zero'th" item.   It's not an array, so it doesn't have bounds - maybe that's what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, I think I was thinking that 'zero' was the first item, but that the count would equal 'one'.

Comment: I've edited my orig code by adding 'SUB1' and adding a check for REMatches.Count <= 0.  which calls the RE6 function.  This also throws an error, although it's a 'type mismatch' error.  I've added a check for the REMatches.Count, but there is still an error.